# Do not confirm Edit on Press ENTER with AG GRID REACT

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Is there any way to stop the default behaviour of an AG GRID cell on enter event ?

I tried e.preventDefault() nothing seems to stop it from exiting edit mode when I press enter, I'm trying to do a custom logic on press enter and it's not allowing me to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further looking, I found a function called `supressKeyboardEvent` it takes `params` as arguments and returns a boolean (Whether should the event be suppressed or not).


For more details refer to this official Ag grid source : https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/keyboard-navigation/#suppress-keyboard-events